# Atribuindo uma chave e um valor a um objeto

Tags: php, array

Eu atribuo o resultado de uma consulta SQL utilizando PDO (`PDO::FETCH_OBJ`) a uma variável, e com essa variável eu acesso os valores da consulta como se fosse um objeto.

**Exemplo de uma array como objeto:**

```
<?php

$obj = (object) array('foo' => 'bar', 'property' => 'value');

echo $obj->foo; // prints 'bar'
echo $obj->property; // prints 'value'

?>
```

**Dúvida:**

Caso a consulta me retornar vazia e eu quiser atribuir manualmente nessa array uma chave e um valor como objeto, como faço?

Comment: Sim. Basicamente isso. Achei que precisasse de mais código para atribuir uma nova chave e valor a uma array do tipo stdClass vazia.

Comment: STD é uma classe anonima, você pode criar as propriedades diretamente sem problema

Comment: Além de poder iterar tais objetos com se fossem arrays convencionais pois a stdClass tem nativamente a funcionalidade provida por Traversable (apesar de não responder a um `instanceof`). Mas, ironicamente, ela não pode ter seus itens acessados com a notação de colchetes de array pois não implementa sequer a funcionalidade provida pela interface ArrayAccess.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Duas maneiras de se fazer isso:

```
// 1: cast para object
$obj = (object) array();
$obj->foo = 10;
var_dump($obj);

// 2: instância de stdClass
$o = new stdClass();
$o->foo = 'bar';
var_dump($o);
```

<sup>http://ideone.com/wyaG2m</sup>

Em resumo, basta atribuir algo a uma propriedade e ela passa a existir no objeto.

E esclarecendo, não existe "array do tipo object" ou "array do tipo stdClass". O que você faz com `(object)` é converter para objeto. Se aquilo já não nasceu como objeto, passa a ser um objeto simplesmente (ou instância de `stdClass`), e não um "objeto do tipo x".