# Problema adicionar propriedade ao stdClass php

Tags: php

eu obtenho por meio de uma consulta ao banco de dados os resultados em **stdClass**. Ate aqui tudo bem, mas terei que adicionar uma propriedade nova no resultado.
Alguém saberia me ajudar a fazer isso, andei dando uma pesquisada mas não tive existo.

Como esta:

```
array (
  0 => 
    object(stdClass)
      public 'aaaaaaa' => string '3'
      public 'aaaaaaaa' => string 'bbbbb'
  1 => 
    object(stdClass)
      public 'aaaaaaa' => string '4'
      public 'aaaaaaaa' => string 'ccccccc'
```

O que quero:

```
array (
  0 => 
    object(stdClass)[66]
      public 'aaaaaaa' => string '3'
      public 'aaaaaaaa' => string 'bbbbb'
      public 'nova' => string 'yyyy'
  1 => 
    object(stdClass)[66]
      public 'aaaaaaa' => string '4'
      public 'aaaaaaaa' => string 'ccccccc'
      public 'nova' => string 'cccc'
```

Estou tentando por meio do foreach:

```
foreach ($variavel as $key => $value) {

}
```

Comment: Não seria apenas `$value->nova = 'yyyy'`?

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss cara estava quebrando a cabeça e nem lembrei de pegar pelo valor. Era isso mesmo, você me salvou. Obrigado. Como coloco como a resposta correta este seu comentario?

Comment: [Atribuindo uma chave e um valor a um objeto](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/40270)